# raise exceptions from scrapy middleware

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I'm trying to raise exceptions from Scrapy spider middleware. According to docs from process_spider_input(response, spider) method I can raise exceptions and it works fine (response not proceeding after raising) but in output logs i see:

```
[scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <POST ...> (referer: ...)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\yudin_an\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 42, in process_spider_input
    result = method(response=response, spider=spider)
  File "E:\Projects\scrapy\src\test\test\middlewares.py", line 39, in process_spider_input
    raise BaseException("exception") from None
```

(links are working, I just hide them)

I want to supress somehow ERROR logging message and don't get them in my STDERR. I don't understand why it is error massage, because raising exception is behavior that i need and make sense for me. Perhaps I want to print message that this exception raised as warning or even info. Can anyone explain me why i got error message and what should I do to supress or fix it

Comment: Then you find a suitable point to handle the exception (maybe in later middleware and its served its purpose) and suppress it?

Comment: Post your middleware source code

Comment: Thank's for your comments, Jon and Tarun. Source code of middleware doesn't important here. i just raise exception directly for each (first) request - for testing.
Jon, your suggest returned me to docs. I try it and what I get: message from the next middleware added and appeared before ERROR message. So I read the docs one more time (It's all my bad english, sorry) and look to this sentence: "If it raises an exception, Scrapy won’t bother calling any other spider middleware process_spider_input() and will call the request errback". This ERROR message printed where no errback function set